# Using imap_pop under php on wamp server 2.4

Tags: php, email, gmail, wampserver, imap-open

I am trying to access gmail via php running under wampserver 2.4.  For simplicity, this is from a localhost (the actual application is much more complex).

Following some standard examples, I am able to both receive (via pop or imap) and send (via smtp) emails through gmail -- but ONLY if the "Less secure apps" feature of gmail is enabled
(https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). Of course, one must first enable pop and/or imap on the gmail settings page 
(https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop)

While this works, I would like php to work with a "more secure technology" -- i.e. SSL and TLS. Any ideas?

The following code is used:

*for retrieving email.*

```
   $ato="{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
    $auser="myaddress@gmail.com";
    $apwd="mypwd";

    $mbox = imap_open($ato,$auser,$apwd,NULL,1)   or die("can't connect: " . print_r(imap_errors())); // just do one login

      $stuff=imap_check($mbox); // get and print basic information (such as # of emails) 
      var_dump($stuff);
```

*and for sending email* (using the PEAR package)
Note that for the following to work, I had to first enable the php_openssl php setting (using the php - phpSettings option under the wampserver popup menu).

```
 require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $to = 'someone@foo.org ';
     $subject = 'Hi!';
     $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $headers = array(
      'From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject
    );

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'mypwd'
     ));

     $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

     if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
         echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
    } else {
        echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
    }
```

Based on various postings, I have tried enabling ssl_module and imagemap_module under apache extensions; and the php_sockets  under php settings. They made no difference.  I have read that configuring php with imap-ssl can matter, but I have no idea how to do that.

Here is the proper response I get when using the pop example above (using my  username and password) -- when gmail's "access for less secure apps" is enabled:

```
    object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'Date' => string 'Thu, 22 Jan 2015 01:06:37 -0500 (Eastern Standard Time)' (length=55)
  public 'Driver' => string 'pop3' (length=4)
  public 'Mailbox' => string '{gmail-pop.l.google.com:995/pop3/notls/ssl/novalidate-cert/user="myemial@gmail.com"}INBOX' (length=99)
  public 'Nmsgs' => int 153
  public 'Recent' => int 1
```

and when I Disable "less secure apps"

```
Array ( [0] => [AUTH] Web login required: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 [1] => Too many login failures ) can't connect: 1
```

BTW: using IMAP 
   $ato="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/imap/ssl}INBOX";
yields:

```
Array ( [0] => Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/imap/ssl}INBOX: invalid remote specification ) can't connect: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmail considers only the OAUTH2 login method to be secure.  See the following article for details:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol

Comment: Thanks, that mostly makes sense. Now the hard part: how to code this into the imap_open ... sequence. Google does have a php library to generate oauth stuff. But,  documentation and examples on how to use it are not obvious.  Any suggestions on where to look.